# How to Un-Mask jquery.maskedinput Phone Number for DB Insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am working with `jquery.maskedinput.min.js` in an MVC web app and I am having a hard time removing the phone number mask.

Js:-

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
    });
    $(function unMaskFunc() { //This doesn't work...
        $("#phone").unmask(); 
    });
</script>
}
```

Next I have my phone number field in my form:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "phone" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

And finally the submit button that is supposed to call the unmask function on click but does not work:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" onclick="unMaskFunc()" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

It inserts in the sql db with the mask and I only want the numbers. No matter where I place the js it either renders the mask in the textbox and inserts the mask or the mask won't render with validation. I really want to use the unmask function from the min.js file!

Any help would be awesome.. I am still new so I think I am missing something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Are you fine with the mask being removed on the server side?

Comment: If you project is mvc why you don't use data annotation like 'RegularExpression'?

Comment: @Hadee I have tried that but it only validates after you click submit. I need something that has prevents the wrong number in the first place.

Comment: you need add relative 'jqueryval' and 'jquery' scripts to your view to enable client side validation.  add them to 'BundleConfig' and then and 'BundleConfig' to master view. Or simply add them directly to your view, at the end by something like :
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert the masked output to a varchar in the DB without the mask, you can do this on the server side.

```
if (model.PhoneNo != null)
   model.PhoneNo = new string(model.PhoneNo.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

This will you give a string with only the numbers which can be inserted into the DB.